# State maintenance among components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, reactive-programming

I am new to react. I have some questions about maintain the state among components. I have issues with maintain the states. It may be a big question.

Simple form: Where I can manintain the state if I have more than 3+ components?

Detail: for ex, I have the below components

```
Main.js - 
   Filter.js
      Dropdown1.js
      Dropdown2.js
   Result.js
      ViewDetails.js
          PopulateDataForView.js
```

**Main.js** - Main component which contains the Filter and Result component.

**Filter.js** - Contains the below Dropdown elements

**Dropdown1.js** - options added using api call

**Result.js** - it will display the record based on the selection in the Filter components. So basically it will get the details from the Filter.js

**ViewDetails.js** - if any record clicked in the result.js, this component will display the details about that row ID.

**PopulateDataForView.js** - It's a helper component for viewDetails component. 
it will populate some data and give it to ViewDetails.js

Filter.js have it's own state to maintain the dropdown onchange values and it will send the data to Result.js. Result.js also have it's own states.

Result.js get the data from Filter.js and make the axios call and display the results.

So, here where I can maintian the states? Which component is the right place to maintain it or i can use more than one component to maintain it?

Comment: You can maintain states at filter and result component. Let it's child elements(dropdown) be pure presentational components with no state to be maintained

Comment: main.js is a parent of filter and result component. I saw maintaining the states in parent component is good. so, in this case, maintain state in filter and result is recommendable?

Comment: I agree with your perception. Main business logic should be performed in parent component. But here it is child and its having its own subchild. So in this scenario if there is some reasoning/logic to be maintained for UI (except business logic) then you should have state in filter and result

Comment: I think maintaining state in Main.js  and keeping all other component pure will be a good approach. 
As change in dropdown.js is associated with api call, you can do the api call in Main.js and easily map the result to Result.js and its child component.

Comment: If keeping all api calls and maintain all state in main.js, then main.js may have around 50+ state (for my webapp) variables. Maintaining that much amount of state in main.js is good practice?